# Networking: Cannot ping across router in one direction (can ping in other direction)

Tags: debian, networking, raspberry-pi, router, pfsense

Here's my network topology:

- ISP: 192.168.0.1
- pfSense: (ip dhcp) <-> 192.168.1.1
- pfSense does outbound NAT such that all traffic passing out of interface (ip dhcp) is NAT to map all "internal" addresses to a single IP
- This is to prevent problems where the ISP router sees traffic destined for (eg) 192.168.2.X and it doesn't know what 192.168.2.X is. (I can't set static routes.)
- Raspberry-Pi: (ip dhcp from pfSense) <-> 192.168.2.254
- Other devices receive IP addresses from Raspberry-Pi via dnsmasq.

```
ISP [192.168.0.1] <-> [DHCP IP] pfSense [192.168.1.1] <->
    [192.168.1.220 DHCP reserved] R-Pi [192.168.2.254] <->
    devs on my network incl 192.168.2.101
```

Here is an example of such a device:

- 192.168.2.101
- Ping to 192.168.2.254 = ok
- Ping to 192.168.1.1 = fail

In reverse:

- 192.168.1.1 (pfSense) can ping 192.168.2.101 successfully

On pfSense I have set a gateway (LAN interface) up with IP 192.168.1.220 (value given by pfSense DHCP, although this is a reserved IP for obvious reasons)

I have also set a static route to net 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.220.

Raspberry Pi iptables is flushed.

Here is a packet capture of ping requests made using machine 192.168.2.101 to the pfSense box (192.168.1.1).

```
14:43:41.042222 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 1, length 64
14:43:42.050051 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 2, length 64
14:43:43.074070 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 3, length 64
14:43:44.098041 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 4, length 64
14:43:45.122050 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 5, length 64
14:43:46.146034 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 6, length 64
14:43:47.169980 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 7, length 64
14:43:48.193955 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 8, length 64
14:43:49.218050 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 9, length 64
14:43:50.241974 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 10, length 64
14:43:51.265982 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 11, length 64
14:43:52.290022 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 12, length 64
14:43:53.313970 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 13, length 64
14:43:54.337960 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 14, length 64
14:43:55.361926 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 15, length 64
14:43:56.385927 IP 192.168.2.101 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 2215, seq 16, length 64
```

It looks like the pfSense router simply does not bother trying to reply. Which seems really strange, because I can ssh into `192.168.2.101` using machines on the `192.168.1.0` network, so the pfSense box clearly knows where to send traffic destined for a `192.168.2.0` address.

I'm not sure what else to test to diagnose this?

## Raspberry-Pi `dnsmasq.conf`

```
dhcp-lease-max=11
server=192.168.2.1
server=192.168.1.1

interface=eth0
dhcp-range=192.168.2.128,192.168.2.199,255.255.255.0,24h

dhcp-host=... some stuff here...
```

## `ip route`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.220 metric 204 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.220 metric 204 
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.2.254 metric 202
```

Comment: Try checking the firewall logs. I do not think pfSense allows ICMP by default.

Comment: I believe this could be either a firewall or a routing problem. You said that the raspi iptables are flushed, but, in order to properly diagnose this problem, we probably need to know the firewall configuration of the other machines involved as well as their routing tables. I could also be useful to know the dnsmasq configuration on the raspi and the netmasks of the interfaces. Most of the times I've seen this behaviour, it's a routing problem: I suspect some routing issue is preventing 192.168.1.1's ICMP response from reaching back at 192.168.2.101.

Comment: Now, with respect to your comments about SSH, you have to remember that routing decisions can be affected by the source address of the packets and that SSH uses TCP, which is a Layer 4 (transport) connection protocol, so it is sufficient that the connecting machine can ping the remote, and you said there is no problem there.

Comment: @Bungicasse Presumably you refer to the firewall logs on the pfSense system. I checked these and indeed there are many block actions. But why would this be the case?

Comment: @HermógenesOliveira I have added some information regarding dnsmasq config. I will also add the routing tables in a moment.

Comment: OK. So, a possible source of issues is that `dnsmasq.conf` is telling the raspi's DHCP clients that it is going to route traffic on the 192.168.2.0/24 subnet only (see `dhcp-range` netmask parameter) and those clients are probably setting their routing tables accordingly. Therefore, packets originating on those clients would probably have trouble reaching machines on the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

Comment: @HermógenesOliveira thanks for the info - can you explain this in more detail? Which lines in the config file are causing this issue?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://sources.debian.org/src/dnsmasq/2.80-1/dnsmasq.conf.example/?hl=152:163#L152), the third argument in the `dhcp-range` line gives the netmask. Based on your description of the network, dnsmasq will probably not be able to guess an appropriate value, so you have to set it up explicitly. Your current value `255.255.255.0` covers only a single /24 subnet, in this case 192.168.2.0/24. Since you want the raspi's DHCP clients to be able to reach machines on the 192.168.1.0/24 address space, you probably need to set this value accordingly.

Comment: @HermógenesOliveira I'm confused about what netmask means in this context. I don't want the DHCP server to be allocating IP's to other hosts on other networks. So I am confused as to what the netmask actually "does" in this situation. From your explanation it sounds like the netmask has nothing to do with the allocation of DHCP addresses, but relates to routing of traffic somehow? Why is a netmask required in this situation at all and what does it do?